# How can i read the docx file from onedrive using Microsoft graph rest API

Tags: python, python-2.7, microsoft-graph-api

I am not able to read the docx file from one drive using Microsoft Graph rest API

I tried using the download file and using that response.content but it gives me not readable data by human eye
[Output Image (content i am reciveing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHWVZ.png)

Comment: Can you show the output that you get?

Comment: Please check the link of image i have updated

Answer (score 0):

The response you get is a stream of raw bytes. To get the docx file, just write the bytes file like below.

```
f = open('DocumentName.docx', 'wb')
f.write(r.content)
f.close()
```